# SQL show a column data only when another column is NULL

Tags: sql

I need to get data from a column only when a different column is NULL.

| id_user | session | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 1 | 10 |
| 201 | 1 | 10 |
| 202 | 1 | NULL |

From the above I need the SQL query to only return the id_user for the event which is NULL

I am not so sure what the best method is.

Comment: use { SELECT id_user FROM table_name WHERE event IS NULL }  query

Comment: `case when event is null then id_iser else null end`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this with WHERE IS NULL clause.

```
SELECT id_user FROM YourTable WHERE event IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `WHERE event IS NULL` in the query to check if the event is null,
this should get you the data you need.

in your case an example can be

```
SELECT id_user FROM yourTable WHERE event IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks,
I guess i need to add a select within my initial select because my query is quite big and joins different tables together

Comment: here is my query
SELECT
Columns AS "names",...
"instructor_id" = (select lcsi.id_user WHERE lcsi.id_date IS NULL)
from learning_course lc
left join..
left join lt_course_session_instructor lcsi on lcs.id_session = lcsi.id_session

there is something wrong because the column doesnt return the correct data it just shows 0 when it should show the id_user

Comment: apologies for the poor formatting

Comment: @redhood 
In this case maybe you would have done better to specify your case more by putting the whole query and the whole db, so it is a bit difficult for me to help you